# Use SWUpdate on Debian 10 + grub

Tags: debian, updates, ota, swupdate

Does anyone know how I can use SWUpdate on a standard Debian system? I found a lot of information about SWUpdate in combination with Yocto or Raspberry PI but nothing about e.g. Debian which is running on an internal SSD.

My goals:
I have an embedded hardware based on Intel i5-6300U, 8GB ram and integrated 240GB SSD. Now I would install Debian and set up OTA updates with SWUpdate. I wanted to create the image for the rootfs in a virtual environment (e.g. VirtualBox). Afterwards it should be uploaded to the devices.

Answer (score 0):

There is debian packages, SWUpdate was merged into experimental, and since Ubuntu 20.10 you can install it via apt-get.

Comment: Thanks I found it. Can you get me a hint how can I started with it? Do I need a special disk partitioning before and how can I create an image from an exists debian installation?